# How query images/videos in custom folders using ContentResolver in Android?

Tags: android, android-gallery, mediastore, android-contentresolver

I have a custom folder in the `Pictures` directory, like this`Pictures/MyFolder`. It has images in `MyFolder`. Here is how to query the images using ContentResolver on `MyFolder` folder only.

I tried this

```
Cursor mediaCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"),
                null,
                MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH + " like ? ",
                new String[]{"%MyFolder%"},
                null);
```

But it contains other files also. Or is any alternate to content resolver?

Comment: `It has images in MyFolder.` You should start telling who put that images there and how.

Comment: `But it contains other files also. ` What do you mean? Did other apps put images there too? And using getContentResolver is irrelevant. You are querying the MediaStore.

Comment: Thanks for reply @blackapps, I putted the images in that particular folder using  `File imageFolder = new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES, context.getString(R.string.app_name));  ContentValues newImage = new ContentValues(); newImage.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, imageFolder.toString()); context.getContentResolver().insert(collection, newImage);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below function to get the images from the folder.

```
private void getImageFolderList() {
    String[] projection = new String[] { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN };
            Uri images = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN;
            Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(images, projection, // Which
                                                                        // columns
                                                                        // to return
                    null, // Which rows to return (all rows)
                    null, // Selection arguments (none)
                    orderBy + " DESC" // Ordering
            );
            ArrayList<String> imagePath;
            if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                String bucket, date;
                int bucketColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME);
                int dateColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN);
                do {
                    bucket = cur.getString(bucketColumn);
                    date = cur.getString(dateColumn);
                    if (!allFolder.contains(bucket)) {
                        allFolder.add(bucket);
                    }
                    imagePath = listImageByFolder.get(bucket);
                    if (imagePath == null) {
                        imagePath = new ArrayList<String>();
                    }
                    imagePath.add(cur.getString(cur
                            .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)));
                    listImageByFolder.put(bucket, imagePath);
                } while (cur.moveToNext());
            }
    }
```

Comment: imagePath has the list of images and listImageByFolder is the  HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>.

Comment: Thanks @RinkiSharma, What `allFolder` variable refering?

Comment: It works fine. But I want image only at `MyFolder`. Cursor running for every folder in `Pictures directory`. It is possible to stop the redundant runs?

Comment: `BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME` is only available from api 29