# How delete images/videos in custom folders using ContentResolver in Android?

Tags: android, android-gallery, mediastore, android-contentresolver

I have a custom folder in the Pictures directory, like this `Pictures/MyFolder`. It has images in MyFolder. Here is how to delete the images using ContentResolver on `MyFolder` only. Or is any alternative ways to delete the image. It is on android 11.

I queried images using the following snippets

```
String[] projection = new String[]{
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN};
        Uri images = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN;
        Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(images,
                projection, // Which
                // columns
                // to return
                null, // Which rows to return (all rows)
                null, // Selection arguments (none)
                orderBy + " DESC" // Ordering
        );
```

Comment: There is no code that deletes anything. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68654308/how-query-images-videos-in-custom-folders-using-contentresolver-in-android

Comment: If you have the uri of an image file you can use getContentResolver().delete(uri).

Comment: Thanks for reply @blackapps , How to get assest uri by using Cursor ?. I tried this `new File(imagePath).getUri()` it is not working... Is any way to get URI directly?